# how to test windows 10 store apps using coded UI testing?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

[image: trying to use Xaml.launch(automation id for the app)]

trying to launch an app from a coded ui testing project for windows app store.

Comment: my os is windows 10 and i am trying to launch an app through Xaml.launch(automation id) but it is throwing an error "you can not run coded ui test for windows store app on this plateform ".
it is working fine for windows 8 and 8.1 i don't know what's wrong with windows 10.Please help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably chosen the wrong visual studio project. Under the Create new Project you have the categories Test and Windows. If you select CodedUI from the Test category, then you use the CodedUI solution for Win32, .Net forms, Wpf applications and web applications. But there is also a CodedUI project under the windows category. The project type you need to pick is called CodedUI Test Project (Universal Windows)
See screenshot here:
[image]

When you have the wrong type of project it will throw the exeption. Unfortunately at this moment these two types of projects are realy different and you need to be explicit in the type of project you use.

Comment: i have selected this only..can you run the test method you created ?I think you will also get the same error